# Function.prototype.bind does not work in IE even in versions where it is supposed to be supported

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The following script does not work in IE 9, IE 10, IE 11

```
var a = location;
var b = 'toString'
var c = a[b].bind(a);
c(); // "Invalid calling object in IE"
```

Any workarounds for this?

Edit - The MDN shim provided in the linked question do not work!! And they are for IE 8! My question for IE > 8 where Function.bind is "supported".

Comment: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: Regarding your edit, you need to provide details about what *exactly* the problem is, because the answer in the duplicate question indeed answers your question as far as we can tell.

Comment: I have provided a concise example as to why Function.bind does not work in IE > 8 where it is supposed to be supported. The MDN shim provided in the other answer also does not work and gives the same error as mentioned in the question. You can try it out.

Comment: Is your page running in Standards Mode? This is a requirement for IE 9+ support. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: @scunliffe Yes. I have hosted a sample page at inian.co/page.html It throws an error in IE

Comment: `window.location` is a host object as is its `toString()` method. I don't believe there's any guarantee that `toString` will behave identically to a native function. Even `.call()` doesn't seem to work with that method.

Comment: @cookiemonster but `c()` should behave identical to `location.toString()` right?

Comment: Theoretically it would seem that way, but again, since `location` and its methods are host objects, you lose some of those guarantees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer is notorious for giving you direct access to Host objects (like `location` and `console`), without providing a "Javascript wrapper" around them like Chrome and Firefox do.

To simulate the "bind" functionality, you'd have to use a wrapper function, which isn't pretty, but will do the job:

```
function bindHost(bindingContext, methodName) {
    return function(arg0, arg1, arg2) {
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
            bindingContext[methodName]();
        } else if (arguments.length === 1) {
            bindingContext[methodName](arg0);
        } else if (arguments.length === 2) {
            bindingContext[methodName](arg0, arg1);
        } else {
            // (Repeat the else-if blocks, if you require 3+ args)
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var locationToStringBound = bindHost(location, 'toString');
locationToStringBound();
```

Answer (score 3):

`location` is [a host object](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.8) - even in ES5 host objects are guaranteed to do only one thing - not follow the specification for normal JavaScript objects.

> [It] is expected that the computational environment of an ECMAScript program will provide not only the objects and other facilities described in this specification but also certain environment-specific host objects, **whose description and behaviour are beyond the scope of this specification** except to indicate that they may provide certain properties that can be accessed and certain functions that can be called from an ECMAScript program. *[emphasis added]*

`toString` is not part of [the guaranteed interface of all JS objects (including host objects)](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) - therefore *anything* is possible, including, unfortunately the behavior you have described.